# Make Cmd+1..9 to switch tabs in Safari?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, keyboard-navigation

Is there a way to make <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> switch to the first tab, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to switch to the second and so on..?

I'd much rather not use SIMBL..

Comment: As an aside: Ctrl-Tab goes to the next tab.

Comment: wow, this is so annoying. wish there was a simpler way than the ones listed below as of 7/2011.

Comment: FWIW, I've been using Chrome which uses Cmd+1..9 for switching tabs, and a few other things I missed from Firefox (like middle-clicking tabs to close them)

Answer (score 2):

One (still relatively hacky) option would be to assign shortcuts to AppleScripts like this:

```
tell app "Safari" to tell window 1 to set current tab to tab 1

---

tell app "Safari" to tell window 1 to set current tab to last tab
```

You could use Automator services or third party apps like [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) or [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) to assign the shortcuts.

Comment: Without FastScripts, one could go nuts by registering a handler for [a dedicated URL protocol](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/index.html). Then, in Safari, bookmarks those `tabx://` links in the first 9 slots of the bookmarks bar. ;-) Or, less adventuristic: create an Automator "service", like described in [How can I program the function keys on my MacBook?](http://superuser.com/questions/72468/how-can-i-program-the-function-keys-on-my-macbook/97813#97813)

Comment: You can also use [QuickSilver](http://qsapp.com) to associate a keyboard shortcut to an AppleScript, see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/468595/xcode-multiple-key-bindings-per-function) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Check this new [plugin](https://github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching) (OSX Lion only):

> Safari Tab Switching is a Safari SIMBL plugin which allow switching
>   between tabs using Cmd+1-9.

Comment: The user doesn't want a simbl plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is no real non-hacky solution, but you can always use cmd + shift + (left or right arrow key) to switch the tab on the left or the tab on the right. I've always found that useful.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use https://github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching . If you find it does not work on later versions of OSX or Safari (I have it running on v8), you can look at 
https://github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching/issues/27

Answer (score -2):

Safari > Preferences > Tabs > "Use cmd-1 through cmd-9 to switch tabs"

Comment: Not sure why this is being down-voted, as of Safari 10.1.2 this is correct.